# Run-time error when using memset

Tags: c, struct, memset

I am new to C and I am using `memset`.
From what I read `memset` replaces part of a section of memory with a char.
When I try to do that my program shuts down and using breakpoints it stops after the line with `memset`.  Not really sure why.

```
void init_TCB (struct TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size)
{
    memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(struct TCB_t));
    getcontext(&tcb->context);
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP;
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t)stack_size;
    makecontext(&tcb->context, function, 0);
}
```

the `sizeof(struct TCB_t)` is 957, `tcb` is the memory location for the `struct`, and `'\0'` is a `char`.

Here is the struct `

```
struct TCB_t
{
struct TCB_t * next;
struct TCB_t * previous;
ucontext_t context;
};
```

and here is where I initialize the struct

```
void start_thread(void (*function)(void))
{
struct stack * stackP = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
struct TCB_t * tcb = (struct TCB_t *)(sizeof(struct TCB_t));
init_TCB (tcb, function, stackP,  8192);
ptr = create_list();
add_to_list( ptr);
```

}

Comment: Show us `getcontext`.

Comment: It all depends on what `tcb` points to when the function is called.

Comment: The `memset` looks Ok based upon what little information you've provided unless the pointer value `tcb` doesn't really point to a properly allocated `struct TCB_t` (you don't show the allocation, so difficult to tell). You also havent't shown how `TCB_t` is defined, so the call to `getcontext(&tcb->context);` is potentially in question.

Comment: getcontext is an internal call to the ucontext_t library

Comment: you are not allocating anything for the `tcb` you are just creating a pointer to somewhere

Comment: `struct TCB_t * tcb = (struct TCB_t *)(sizeof(struct TCB_t));` You're pointing tcb to the _size_ of the structure. Did you mean `struct TCB_t * tcb = malloc(sizeof(struct TCB_t));`?

Comment: This is very, very wrong: `struct TCB_t * tcb = (struct TCB_t *)(sizeof(struct TCB_t));`  With that your call to `memset` invokes UB.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add malloc

Comment: If you didn't include the needless cast to begin with, the compiler would've warned you.

Comment: BTW: `'\0'` is an `int` in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

`struct TCB_t * tcb = (struct TCB_t *)(sizeof(struct TCB_t));`

You're pointing tcb to the size of the structure.

Instead you could allocate space for the structure with `malloc()`:

`struct TCB_t * tcb = malloc(sizeof(struct TCB_t));`

Comment: Won't the call to `memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(struct TCB_t));` still overwrite the pointer to the memory allocated by malloc?

Comment: @EricJ.: No. It uses the pointer to determine where to write. It doesn't write over the pointer. This is fairly clear from the `memset` documentation. (How would you suggest the line be written differently? Recall, C does not have references!)

Comment: Oh, I see.  The declaration is `ucontext_t context;`  I was thinking it was `ucontext_t *context;`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that getcontext is defined as

```
int getcontext(ucontext_t *ucp);
```

> The function getcontext() initializes the structure pointed at by ucp
>          to the currently active context.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html

It expects a pointer to `ucontext_t`, but you are passing all zeroes (a pointer initialized to the address zero).

For reference, see this implementation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext#Example), with the key parts being

```
ucontext_t main_context1;
// ...
getcontext(&main_context1);
```

Note that a valid address (of the stack variable) is passed in, not a pointer to address zero.